# Need regex help for URL rewriting querystrings to friendly URLs

Tags: asp.net, regex, iis-7, url-rewriting

I updated my website CMS and the URL formats have changed. Where previously I had the URL **/blog.aspx?Year=XXXX&Month=YY** I now have **/blog/XXXX/YY**

Can someone help me create a regex for this?

Two additional notes:

- it has to also support simply the year (**/blog.aspx?Year=XXX**)
- the old Month urls use only 1 digit for single digit months (**/blog.aspx?Year=2009&Month=2** instead of **Month=02**)

Here is what I came up with:

```
/blog.aspx[?]Year=([0-9]{4})([&amp;]?)(Month=)?([0-9]*)
```

I can't seem to get it to work, as I still get a 404 on the page when I go to one of the above URLs.

Comment: I have a separate redirect using mappings that redirects /blog.aspx to /blog, and that works. but if I add the querystrings I always get 404, even though this redirect above is higher than the basic one...

Answer (score 0):

Is this workable?

```
/blog.aspx\?Year=([0-9]{4})(?>\&?Month=?([0-9]{1,2})|)
```

works with these input

```
/blog.aspx?Year=1983&Month=2
/blog.aspx?Year=1983
/blog.aspx?Year=1983&Month=12
```

there is this `(?>blabla|moomoo)` syntax.
If it cant find `blabla` match, it will match `moomoo`

Though i suspect regex here is not the root problem, what CMS handles the redirect?

Comment: thanks i'll try it, but how do I tell the redirected url to convert the month to a 2 digit number?

Comment: I will need to know what CMS you're using so we can be sure of the syntax.